# what is the difference between rootConfigClasses in spring and servlet context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I read that Root config class provide application specific configuration such as service class configuration,etc., My doubt is that why we need root config classes. And how servlet context is related to root config classes.

```
package configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class FrontController extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
        

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {DaoConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple: root context is global for all servlets and servlet context is for a particular servlet. The servlet settings can be different for each servlet.